# echo php positioning

Tags: php, css, styles, echo

im doing a form in this link http://jardineselectricos.com/xtatanx/contacto.php, everything works fine, the form just sent me the emails when is filled but, when i recive the echo output all the website mees up. i Would like to know how i can position the output where i want. this is my code.

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="contacto.php" id="form">
    <label for="nombre">Nombre: </label>
    <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Su nombre"/>
    <label for="correo">Correo electrónico: </label>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="nombre@correo.com"/>
    <label for="numero-telefonico">Teléfono móvil: </label>
    <input type="text" name="telefono" placeholder="Introducir nº de telf" />
    <label for="mensaje">Mensaje: </label>
    <textarea name="mensaje" cols="20" rows="6" placeholder="Escriba un mensaje breve..."></textarea>
    <input type="submit" id="enviar" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
    <span id="respuesta">
      <?php
                $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
                $email = $_POST['email'];
                $numero = $_POST['telefono'];
                $mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];
                $from = 'From: UsuarioStrategyResearch'; 
                $to = 'jhonnatanhxc@gmail.com'; 
                $subject = 'Contacto Strategy Research';

                $body = "De: $nombre\n E-Mail: $email\n Movil: $numero\n Mensaje:\n $mensaje";

                if ($_POST['enviar']) {
                if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
                    echo '<p>Tu mensaje ha sido enviado, pronto nos pondrémos en contacto.</p>';
                } else { 
                    echo '<p>Ha habido un error y el mensaje no ha podido ser enviado.</p>'; 
                }
            }
            ?>
    </span>
  </form>
```

The output is always place it like in the middle of the website, it doesnt change if i use an spam or div or if i positionae in the footer or everywhere, it just echo in the same place. i would appreciate your help guys thank you very much.

Comment: So where do you want to output to go?

Comment: i want the output to go inside the span with the id="respuesta" so in that order i think it should appear below the submit button, but instead appears in the middle of the document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page shows you the problem

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/jardines/public_html/xtatanx/contacto.php:57) in /home/jardines/public_html/xtatanx/contacto.php on line 70

That means that the `mail` function needs to modify the HTTP headers but they have already been sent because you've already started outputting the HTML.

You need to make sure you call `mail` before outputting any HTML

```
<?php
// At the top of the file, before any HTML is output
$successfulMail = mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from);
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$numero = $_POST['telefono'];
$mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];
$from = 'From: UsuarioStrategyResearch'; 
$to = 'jhonnatanhxc@gmail.com'; 
$subject = 'Contacto Strategy Research';
$body = "De: $nombre\n E-Mail: $email\n Movil: $numero\n Mensaje:\n $mensaje";
$mailMsg = '';
if ($_POST['enviar']) {
    // Here's the trick, can't call mail after HTML has been output
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
       $mailMsg ='<p>Tu mensaje ha sido enviado, pronto nos pondrémos en contacto.</p>';
    } else {
       $mailMsg ='<p>Ha habido un error y el mensaje no ha podido ser enviado.</p>'; 
    }
}
?>    
...
<form method="post" action="contacto.php" id="form">
    <label for="nombre">Nombre: </label>
    <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Su nombre"/>
    <label for="correo">Correo electrónico: </label>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="nombre@correo.com"/>
    <label for="numero-telefonico">Teléfono móvil: </label>
    <input type="text" name="telefono" placeholder="Introducir nº de telf" />
    <label for="mensaje">Mensaje: </label>
    <textarea name="mensaje" cols="20" rows="6" placeholder="Escriba un mensaje breve..."></textarea>
    <input type="submit" id="enviar" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
    <span id="respuesta"><?php echo $mailMsg ?> </span>
  </form>
```